# Missing macros in Word 365

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, office365

I'm hoping someone can help with this problem. I've just upgraded from preview to Office 365 and the problem is present in both versions (but not in the Office 2010 that I was using before).

Whenever I try to open a Word document, I get the warning:

> The function you are attempting to run contains macros or content that requires macro language support. When this software was installed, you (or your administrator) chose not to install support for macros or controls.

[image: 1]

This does not happen in Excel or PowerPoint.

I have tried following the advice in the warnings (going to the trust centre), but these warnings keep popping up and I don't want to mess up my Office installation (that was done using the standard setting). After a few clicks it disappears, but also asks me about Endnote CWYW X4... I'm wondering if this might be the problem but can't find anything in the web to suggest it is.

Comment: .DOCM files can be edited using the webapp, but macros will run only in 'normal' desktop Word. Do you see the warning even if you simply open Word and not an existing document? Do Word macros still work after you dismiss the warning? From **Programs and Features** in the Control Panel, select Office, click **Change** on the toolbar and then select **Add or Remove Features**. Ensure that **Visual Basic for Applications** is selected under **Office Shared Features** (or similarly worded option). You can also try the **Repair** option and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can open Word OK, but the moment I open a new or existing document, the warning appears (regardless of the version it was saved in). The add/remove only offers a pre-installed or online repair and there are no options in 365 to select what you want to change. I've selected VBA in the Word document options, but still no difference. I've tried the repair option a couple of times but there is no change. The only option I've not tried is a custom installation. I will report back if this works, but if I can't solve this then I may go back to 2010. Driving me nuts! Help!

Comment: OK, so reinstalled ... no custom option offered, but all seemed to be well with no warnings. Then once I had opened a file from the external drive I use for storage, all the warnings again, even when I open a new document. In all I have 7 warnings every time I open a file and another one or two when switching between already open files. I can't believe I am the only person with this problem, so have some hope of a solution. I can't preclude that I am missing something completely obvious, but this is still slowly driving me mad!!! Thanks in advance for any help.