# How do I install Visual Basic for Applications 2013 in Office 365?

Tags: vba, office365

I've recently taken out a subscription to Office 365 and have downloaded the desktop office programs. However, I'm trying to install an EPM excel addin and it's complaining that it needs "Microsoft Visual Basic for Application 2013  or later".

The thing is, all instructions online for Office 2013 involve going to Add/Remove programs and clicking change, which brings up the repair Office 365 dialog instead of allowing me to install the optional VBA component.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can install VBA 2013 when I've got Office 365?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is the same thing you guys have been looking for, but I found I was able to access VBA in Office365 by opening Excel, going to FILE > OPTIONS, select 'Customize Ribbon', add 'Developer' to show in the ribbon. Now simply go to the Developer tab and click 'Visual Basic', which will pop open a new window.

Answer (score 2):

I also got hit with this issue where I needed VBA 2013, but couldn't install it via the 365 installer.

My solution was to borrow a friends' Office 2013 install disc and only install the optional VBA component.

**You don't need to enter a key to install this component!**

Answer (score 2):

Office 365 comes (somehow) in two variants, a desktop or a web application version.

With the desktop version you can use VBA, but not with the web application one.

Have a look here: *[Missing macros in Word 365](https://superuser.com/questions/549248/missing-macros-in-word-365)*

Answer (score 1):

I second Kryten's solution - installing the shared components from "traditional" Office media seemed to bypass the issue for me.

As you can see in my [screenshot](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=92C7C129B2F42162!632&authkey=!AP7zq_7cEzUWRDM&v=3&ithint=photo,.png), VBA does seem to work in Office 365 Pro Plus, which implies to me that VBA is installed with the streaming setup. So potentially the EPM add-in just can't detect it.

I've tried raising a case with Microsoft, asking them to explicitly confirm or deny that VBA is included/supported with Office 365 Pro Plus. They tried fobbing me off with [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/office-applications-service-description.aspx) but when I said "that's not really very helpful" they have suddenly gone very quiet on me.

To be honest the whole terminology around Office 2013/Office 365 is a bit of a joke. What is a software product? What is a cloud/service? I'd like to think I'm getting my head around it but clearly not everyone is, which is causing a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps but...
Make sure that your Developer tab is set to be visible.
Go to File>Options>Customize Ribbon>Main Tabs (on left)
Make sure that there is a check in the box for the Developer tab
OK (save)

Comment: Your doubt is well-placed.  You are correct that this doesn't help with this question.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me. It appeared that VBA was not installed in Office 365, when actually it was -- just hidden.